# DateAxisRenderer wouldn't render when used with knockout binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jqplot

I have written a knockout binding for jqplot, it works perfectly fine with the default renderer. When I use DateAxisRenderer as x axis renderer, it won't draw lines for some reason.

Here is the code which I used, you can see two charts here. One using knockout binding that does not work as intended and another without knockout binding that works as intended.

And the fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/0vauuf13/

Any help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jqplot/1.0.8/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js"></script>

<div id="chart3" style="height:300px;width:600px; "></div>
<div id="chart-container">
  <div id="chart4" style="height:300px;width:600px;" data-bind="jqplot:chartData"></div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

  var line1 = [
    ['2008-06-30 8:00AM', 4],
    ['2008-7-14 8:00AM', 6.5],
    ['2008-7-28 8:00AM', 5.7],
    ['2008-8-11 8:00AM', 9],
    ['2008-8-25 8:00AM', 8.2]
  ];

  var plotOptions = {
    title: 'Customized Date Axis',
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
          formatString: '%b %#d, %#I %p'
        },
        min: 'June 16, 2008 8:00AM',
        tickInterval: '2 weeks'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      lineWidth: 4,
      markerOptions: {
        style: 'square'
      }
    }]
  };
  var plot3 = $('#chart3').jqplot([line1], plotOptions);

  ko.applyBindings({
    chartData: {
      data: line1,
      options: plotOptions
    }
  }, $("#chart-container")[0]);
});


ko.bindingHandlers.jqplot = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {

  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {};
    var data = value.data || [];
    var options = value.options || {};
    if (data.length > 0) {
      if ($(element).data('jqplot')) {
        var plotObject = $(element).data('jqplot');
        //plot.replot(data, options);
        plotObject.destroy();
      }
      $(element).jqplot(data, options);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Call me dumb! I just missed out a square bracket in the data points. The line below wraps the datapoint with `[]` square brackets.

I should have wrapped `line1` data with `[]` before I pass it to ko binding.

```
var plot3 = $('#chart3').jqplot([line1], plotOptions);
```